# CoreData and NSPredicate

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate

I have coredata on my iOS application, but what I am doing is gathering all the values from the table, which in my case is a Questions table, which contains the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * answerA;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * answerB;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * answerC;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * answerD;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * correctAnswer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * question;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * timeStampLastUsed;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * gameType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * continent;
```

I am getting all the values this way:

```
NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Questions" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

What I want is to have in the NSArray *fetchedObjects only the Questions that have a specific game type.

How can I do that with the NSPredicate?

Thanks
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the value of the game type you're looking for, you can use something like this:

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"gameType == %i", 0]];
```

By setting the predicate on your fetch request, it will filter out the results and return only the items you are interested in.

Comment: As gameType is an NSNumber object, I would recommend doing `@"gameType.intValue == %i", 0`. Typically it works if `intValue` is omitted but it is still good practice

Comment: I am now trying to do some more advanced things, I want to get all the game types that are in the europe continent:  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((gameType.intValue == %i) OR (gameType.intValue == %i) OR (gameType.intValue == %i)) AND (continent.intValue == %i)",0,2,3, 0]; but this is not returning me what I expect. I want to get the game types 0,2 and 3 that are from the european continent (0). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your predicate looks to be correct given the parameters you have supplied. What results are you getting, if any? I find it is sometimes easier to create a `predicateWithBlock:` for testing your filtered results and then refactor this back into `predicateWithFormat:` once you have the results you need.

Comment: I am getting zero, no values from my query, which is not possible, I have different gameTypes and most of those games have the flag with continent = 0.

Comment: Your `continent` property is an `NSString`. Perhaps change your predicate to `(continent == %@)` and change your parameter to @"0"?

Comment: Thanks:) Problem solved :) I was doing a search on (@"0"), but I have @"Europe" on the database ;) that was the problem. sorry :)